# Cannot choose build when uploading an update for application

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an application on the appstore and I want to upload an update for it.

I opened appstore connect and added a new version named it 1.0.1 , then named the version on XCode 1.0.1 and archived it and uploaded it and got a message that the update is successful.

But The problem now is that I'm unable to choose the build from appstore connect . It shows me the message "Submit your builds using Xcode or Application Loader. See supported versions" without any ability to choose a build.

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was general problem in the AppStore , now it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you recently uploaded new build & if its not showing means its in processing stage. You can refresh your page or enter check in the Activity Tab. You will see the status of the application.

Once processing is done you will see + option available to select the build.

If your build is not even showing in Activity section than consider there is some issue found during processing stage. In that case Apple will send you mail on your Apple ID about what issue they found in the build. So you can check & resolve accordingly & upload new build.

Hope it will helps to everyone.

Comment: It has been since yesterday when I posted the question , and neither the build appeared nor I received an email from apple saying there is an issue.